# Android AOSP make kernel menuconfig

Tags: android-source

What is kernel 'make menuconfig' in android AOSP

I tried `make kernel` from AOSP. it could build kernel only.
But how about if I want to customize kernel config from menuconfig

Regards
Peter

Comment: what is the output when you run the make menuconfig command ?

Comment: LINUX/android/kernel$ ARCH=arm64 make menuconfig
make: *** No rule to make target 'menuconfig'.  Stop.

Answer (score 2):

There's a config.sh script for menuconfig in android kernel source.

Here's the step:

1. download android kernel source code

   repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest -b BRANCH

   repo sync
2. run menuconfig

   BUILD_CONFIG=common/build.config.gki.aarch64 build/config.sh menuconfig
3. modify menuconfigs and save .config
4. build kernel

   BUILD_CONFIG=common/build.config.gki.aarch64 build/build.sh

Reference: https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building-kernels

Answer (score -1):

Building Android kernels for various devices is documented on [source.android.com](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels). It covers the Android Common Kernels as well as some widely used devices that can be built directly from AOSP. While there are no specific instructions for `make menuconfig`, it contains a [section](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels#customize-config) on how to customize the kernel build with specific kernel configuration options.

Such kernel options can of course be discovered through `make menuconfig` as usual.